# Lattice and things i cannot solve even though it's supposed to be trivial. Guess i'm dumb...

Tags: lattice-orders

this is apparently an easy question, for which i'm kind of struggling. I have to show that $(\mathbb Q \cap [0,\sqrt{2}],\leq)$ is a bounded lattice but not a complete lattice.

Could someone help me please ?

Same for an other question which is : show by reccurence on the number of elements that any finite part of a lattice is bounded.

I'm blocked.

Could someone help me for this question too please ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: what work have you put in to solve these?

Comment: What is [0, square root of 2]? And Q are the rational numbers?

Comment: A good start would be checking the definitions of bounded and complete lattices.

Comment: Oh i'm new here sorry. This is a workshit of 26 questions. and in the questions above i had to prove the different properties of a lattice. And then i'm struggling here. For the reccurence one. I think i have to consider elements like {a1, a2, a3,...,an} and then say that the greast common is a1 v a2 v... van and the least is a1 a2 ^a3 ^.. an. So it's bounded but how to show that it's complete (i.e that it doesn't have an upper bound right ?). But normally i have to show it for an+1, but i litterally don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you know that $(\mathbb Q,\leq)$ is a chain, and that every chain is a lattice.
If you don't know that, then prove it.

Also, every subset of a chain is, again, a chain, and so it's also a lattice (once again, prove it if it is not clear enough to you).

Now there is a problem with this question, which is that you want to prove that set to be a bounded lattice.
In Lattice Theory, a bounded lattice is a lattice which has a minimum element (usually denoted by $0$ or $\bot$) and a maximum element (usually denoted by $1$ or $\top$).
Other notations may occur.

But your lattice $L$ doesn't have a maximum element.
Indeed, if $a \in L$, i.e., $a$ is a rational number such that $a \leq \sqrt{2}$ (and thus, $a<\sqrt{2}$), then, there's still some rational number $b$ such that $a<b<\sqrt{2}$, and so $a$ is not the maximum.

Perhaps you'r interested in other notion of boundedness, which is based in the distances between elements of a set, and then the lattice would be bounded in that sense (since $\sup \{d(x,y) : x,y \in L\}$ is finite).

To prove that the lattice is not complete, it is enough the above observation that it doesn't have a maximum element (all complete lattices are bounded in the lattice theoretic sense).

Comment: oh thanks i didn't think to solve it that way. By showing that the upper bound can be infinite so there is no upper bound. Thanks !

Comment: @Nyway You might want to take a look at this link: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck!

Comment: oh okay, i'm sorry ^^

Comment: but could you help me for the second question ?

Comment: @Nyway It is not clear to me what is a bounded part of a lattice. If it was what I mentioned in the fifth paragraph, then in the finite case that would be trivial in most cases (depending on the exact definition). Perhaps you should add some context, and preferably, ask that one in a different question.